# Schedule sql job to run last day but1

Tags: sql-server

I was wondering how to schedule a job that run Last but 1 day of every month

for ex:

in Sep the job needs to run on 29th (as 30th is last day in sep),

in Oct  the job needs to run on 30th (as 31st is last day in  Oct)

in Nov29 the job needs to run on 29th  ( as 30th is the last day of in Nov)

likewise every month as a continuous process.

I know we can schedule job to run on 1, 2,3,4 and last day of every month.

Please advice.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this.

Closest thing you could do is schedule the job to run every day, and start the job with some kind of logic that says, "if this is not the second-to-last day of the month, do nothing.   Otherwise proceed with the rest of the job.".

Comment: Thanks a lot .. that what i am going to do